# Partially left truncated data in bivariate time series, one series is missing data what to do?

Tags: time-series, garch, finance, truncation

I have two time series of futures Settlement Prices where I am to model the systematic volatility of the settlement prices for these two time series.
My plan is to:

1. Calculate the logged returns.
2. Fit a VAR model to the data. Denote the residuals by, $u_t$.
3. Fit an MGARCH model to the residuals $u_t$.
4. Infer on the parameters.
5. Forecast.

I hope this plan is alright. However, my issue is that one of my time series are left truncated (I suppose both are in a certain sense) and I can't seem to find out what to do about it.
The time series do share the same endpoint and the data are equidistant, but one is missing data in the beginning.

After some googling it seems like its possible to setup some sort of truncated distribution, but I've only found that for a single variable (and mostly survival analysis), and I obviously do not know the distribution of my data.

How do I approach this problem? Any sources or hints would be great, thank you.

Comment: This does not sound like truncation in the traditional/technical sense. Do you mean you have data for periods $(1,\dots,T)$ for $x_{1,t}$ and $(k,\dots,T)$ for $x_{2,t}$ where $k>1$? If so, there is no way around it, you will have to discard the first $k-1$ data points for $x_{1,t}$ and then analyze the remaining period where both time series are available.

Comment: @Richard Hardy, Yes this is exactly the case. I think I have misunderstood the meaning of truncation then, how is the setup you have there not truncation?

Comment: Truncation would be based on values of the series, not on values of the time index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not sound like truncation in the traditional/technical sense. Truncation would be based on values of the variables, not on values of the time index. E.g. you would not have data on $x_{2,t}$ whenever $x_{2,t}>C$ for some constant $C$. Meanwhile, you have data for periods $(1,\dots,T)$ for $x_{1,t}$ and $(k,\dots,T)$ for $x_{2,t}$ where $k>1$ regardless of what values the variables take.

You will have to discard the first $k−1$ data points for $x_{1,t}$ and then analyze the remaining period where both time series are available.